# On the number of optimal prefix-free binary codes

Tags: information-theory, trees, coding-theory

Let $T$ be a text of length $L$ containing the symbols $$\mathcal{A}=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\},$$ where each symbol appears at least once and no other symbol appears in $T$.

Define the weights $$\mathcal{W} = \Big\{w_1 = \frac{c_1}{L}, \ldots, w_n = \frac{c_n}{L}\Big\},$$ where $c_i$ is the number of occurrences of $a_i$ in $T$.

Given $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{W}$, one can run Huffman's algorithm to find an optimal prefix-free binary code $$\mathcal{E} =\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n\},$$ where $e_i$ is the encoding for $a_i$.

Optimality of $\mathcal{E}$ means that the quantity $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i l_i$$ is minimum among all other encodings, where $l_i$ is the bit-length of $e_i$.

Optimal prefix-free binary codes are not unique in general. My goal is to establish some bounds on the number of optimal prefix-free binary codes for a given pair $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{W})$.

An optimal prefix-free binary code can be represented as a full binary tree. In particular, each leaf corresponds to a symbol, and every edge is labeled with either $0$ or $1$. The codeword $e_i$ is obtained by reading the path from the root to $a_i$.

The number of full binary trees with $n$ leaves is given by $$C_{n-1} = \frac{(2(n-1))!}{n!(n-1)!}.$$

Moreover, there are $n!$ ways of assigning symbols to leaves.

As a consequence, the number of optimal prefix-free binary codes for a pair $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{W})$ is bounded from above by $$C_{n-1}n!=\frac{(2(n-1))!}{(n-1)!} \sim \sqrt{2}\Big(\frac{4(n-1)}{e}\Big)^{n-1}.$$

On the other hand, given a tree and a unique way of assigning symbols to leaves, there are $2^{n-1}$ ways of labeling the tree with $0$s and $1$s (for each internal node one can label the left child with $0$ or $1$, and do the opposite for the right child).

Therefore, the number of optimal prefix-free binary codes for a pair $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{W})$ is bounded from below by $2^{n-1}$.

My questions are:

1. Are the bounds correct?
2. Are there better bounds?
3. How can I use the fact that I know $\mathcal{W}$?
4. Is there an efficient method for computing the number of optimal prefix-free binary codes for a pair $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{W})$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51843/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4522876/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: In Huffman's algorithm there are a number of places in which you make an arbitrary choice between different symbols, so usually people use 0, 1 but you could use 1, 0 instead. Your question doesn't seem very difficult to answer in that all you have to do is, for a particular case, just add up the number of choices $n$ that can be made and then exponentiate that as $2^n$. So you really are counting the number of choices that can be made of arbitrary symbols.

Comment: @SuzuHirose couldn't there be optimal prefix-free binary codes (OPBCs) that cannot be generated using Huffman's algorithm? It seems you are assuming that your procedure will generate all of them. All I know is that Huffman's algorithm generates an OPBC, but I don't know if every OPBC can be obtained by running Huffman's algorithm.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Not every OPBC can be obtained by running Huffman's algorithm. One example, a depth-w binary tree with four leaves, where the probabilities are, in order, .23, .27, .24, .26 ; Huffman's algorithm always makes the two smallest probabilities siblings.